# How do I design a bus route database?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I want to create a bus route DB in such a way that it gives the result as follows :

**Input :**
     Source = station-X    ,           Destination = station-Y

**Output :** Various bus name/nos. which go through Station-X and Station-Y

So far i have :
**Bus**(bus_no), **Bus_Route**()

```
    Bus(bus_name/no.)
id   |   bus_no
1    |   33
2    |   33A

  Bus_Route(route_id,bus_no)
id   |   route_id  |  bus_no
1    |   route-A   |   33
2    |   route-B   |   33A
```

How do i proceed to store the station names of the respective routes.
I am no database expert, so any help would be valuable .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd be best off creating an extra table holding the STATION - ROUTE relationship. You'd define a many-to-many relationship here, meaning that a station can have many routes, and a route can have many stations.

**busses (only necessary if multiple physical busses exist with same *bus_no*)**

```
id   |   bus_no
---------------
1    |   33
2    |   33A
3    |   33A
```

**bus_routes (both *route_id* and *bus_no* have to be unique values)**

```
route_id  |  bus_no
---------------------
route-A   |   33
route-B   |   33A
```

**stations_routes (many-to-many, route_order tells us the order within the route)**

```
route_id  |  station_id |  route_order
------------------------------------
route-A   |   Egham     |   1
route-A   | Haymarket   |   2
route-A   | Egham Plaza |   3
route-B   |   Egham     |   1
route-B   |   Langley   |   2
```

Comment: nicely depicted :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need the following tables:

```
BUSROUTE: route_id, routenumber  

BUSSTOPS: stop_id, stopname     

BUSROUTESTOPS: route_id, stop_id, displayorder
```

Using the London Underground as an example, the busroute table would hold values like 'Jubilee', 'Central', 'District', 'Bakerloo', etc.

The busstops table would hold the station names, eg Stanmore, Canons Park, Queensbury, Kingsbury, Wembley Park, etc. This table is necessary as a station can service more than one route.

The busroutestops hold the route number, the station name and the order in which the station appears for this route. The primary key would be an amalgamation of route_id and stop_id.

Once you've got past this, you'll probably need a timetable table, which in its simplest form would contain three fields: an id, a route_id and the departure time. It is left 'as an exercise for the reader' how to represent the return journey!

The London Underground was probably *not* a good example as some lines - especially the Northern and District lines - have multiple routes. These would best be treated as separate routes.

Comment: Why `displayorder`? The order of a bus route is not just for display. It is the order the bus physically takes.

Comment: @MartinSmith: it's the name which I generally use. I agree that it's not appropriate here; maybe 'route_order' would be better.

Comment: `step_no` or `leg_no` are typical names for this in routes/trips.